# How to get the object I'm expanding in a TreeView?

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I'm using a TreeView bound to a nested collection of mine. It works fine, but when I expand a node using the little arrow, I would like to get the reference to the object bound to this node. 
I tried using the "sender" and the EventArgs, but I get the TreeViewItem, and not my object.

What can I try ?

Comment: Let us look at your relevant code please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `DataContext` of the `TreeViewItem`.

```
MyObject myObject = (treeViewItem.DataContext as MyObject);
```